# Residue voltage due to gate driver leakage current

Tags: voltage-measurement, hardware, gate-driving, igbt, leakage-current

I want to reduce the leakage current of a gate driver driving an IGBT as I have some residual voltage on the high voltage line LV for communication is on. The residual voltage on the high voltage line is coming from the gate driver VCC due to leakage current of driver.

What could be a possible solution in general to reduce this residual voltage by reducing gate driver leakage current when the high voltage is not there?

[image]

Comment: I almost understood what you mean, but to be 100 %, can you refer to node names from where and where to the current is leaking? How much voltage are we talking about?

Comment: Why did you delete your [earlier post on this subject](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660496/hardware-solution-to-reduce-leakage-current-of-gate-driver). I mean, it's "verbatim" the same question so maybe, you can explain why you felt it necessary to do this? You deleted it 1 minute prior to posting what seems to be an exact copy apart from the title change.

Comment: @winny roughly 8V we can measure between HV+ and HV- when in actual no HV battrey is supplied. Just 12V LV is connected for communication. The current is flowing from 15V Voltage source towards gate driver in the form of leakage currents inducing voltage at each node on the way and then going through body diode of IGBT to the voltage divider resistor which senses that residue voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka because no one was responding to that post thats why i reposted agaian and deleted previous one

Comment: That's against site rules. Please don't do that.

Comment: How much current are we talking about? Does it pump HV to 15 V eventually though the body diodes?

Comment: @Alison I suspect nobody responded for reasons (1) You are focussing **not** on the **real** problem (the disruption of comms) but on the interferer and, you give no information about the comms system that is failing. (2) you refer to IGBTs but, there are no IGBTs disclosed; you appear to be showing BJTs instead and that would imply a different mechanism for interference. (3) you refer to the source of the problem being leakage current (I doubt and possibly others do) and, your question explicitly focusses on that being the problem that needs to be solved. Makes it troublesome to answer.

Comment: @winny its roughly 40 to 50uA . No the max voltage measured is 8V. It doesn't reaches to 15V at any point

Comment: (4) I suspect that the solution is to make the comms more robust to "residual currents and voltages" but, as I said earlier, in order to answer this question relies on **you** being walked backwards through your train of thought (and possible misconceptions) and that probably meant that nobody was willing to take on the task. Stick to the problem; bad comms when some voltages or currents are injected. These are my opinions and nobody else's.

Comment: How much bulk capacitance and parasitic load do you have between HV+ and HV-? Where does the gate driver come from? A commercial offering or something you designed?

Comment: @winny There is no load connected and gate driver we use is dual channel isolated gate driver fro RoHm . Here is data sheet. https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/348/rohm_semiconductor_rohm-s-a0003551162-1-1758061.pdf

Comment: Once you do connect a load, is this a problem?

Comment: @winny didn't checked it but the bottom line is that there should be no voltage at HV lines when battery is not connected in any conditions

Comment: Relay on the outputs? Bleeder resistor?

Comment: @winny No realy used. Only Voltage divider resistors to sensse HV Voltage

Comment: Sure, but how about relay to solve your requirements or increase the bleeder to lower the voltage due to said current? Depletion MOSFET to short the output until commanded to open?

Comment: @winny At first what you are saying make sense but to understand fully, Could you please eloborate your ideas. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, I’ll draw a schematic when I’m at a computer again.

Comment: Can't you just place a P-channel MOSFET on the supply side of the gate driver(s), and switch it off when there is no HV?

Comment: @winny Thank you so much for your assistance and support. I will wait for it

Comment: @EdinFifić For sure, its very much doable to do so but considering we have to add a MOSFET and driving circuit for that, I would like to avoid such option. I can only add passive components in order to solve this issue

Comment: @winny I just saw your solution and thanks for that. I would also like to understand the other solution you gave that is use of bleeder resitance to supress the residue voltage. How exactly that could be implemented

Comment: @Alison How high is your HV+? You never mentioned it. And how low does your off state voltage on HV+ need to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution if you want to get rid of voltage appearing on the output. This may very well be an XY solution where the problem X gets band-aid Y instead of fixing the root cause. But I digress.

M2 is a *depletion* MOSFET which need negative Vgs to turn off, hence the output of the photovoltaic MOSFET driver output appears reversed. You need to drive Clamp_release high at all times when the rails are energized.

You haven't stated your HV+ to HV- voltage. I placed a 1 kV MOSFET. If you need more than that, there are 1700 V ones.

Please adjust R1 according to your Vcc. 100 ohm is just a template.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOVPvF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alternatively, calculate how much static losses you can accept in a bleeder resistor given your max voltage. Now take Uout=Ileak*Rbleeder. Uout low enough? Job done.

Edit: Added R2. Thanks to Edin Fifić.

Comment: I would rather suggest a much safer way to go about your solution: place the bleeder resistor in series with the MOSFET, calculate it for the leakage current of the driver(s) and the low voltage you want to achieve. The MOSFET could possibly let a an extreme amount of current rush through it and cause more damage. With the 50uA leakage current and 500mV HV+ voltage while off, the leakage resistor would need to be about 10kΩ. Adding a very low rating fuse (like 100mA) would prevent the resistor from burning out if bleeder MOSFET is still on when the high voltage comes on.

Comment: Additionally, Alison said that she can only add passive components to solve the issue.

Comment: @EdinFifić Good! I’ll add it when I get home.

Comment: @EdinFifić Thanks for your comment. so does this mean that solution you propsed with bleeder resistance, i dont need M1 and M2 Mosfets which is suggested by Winny in his solution? when you say connect resistance in series with Mosfet then i suppose you mean IGBT?

Comment: @Alison No, he means MOSFET. Have you calculated your bleeder? What values did you end up with?

Comment: @EdinFifić How to calculate the value of bleeder resistor

Comment: @winny No i havent calaculated. I wannted to know how I can calaculate it

Comment: P=U^2/R. Ohm’s law for residual voltage.

Comment: @Alison Sorry, I was busy and away, and hadn't noticed your question until now. To calculate a bleeder resistor, you need to know the leakage current and the maximum acceptable voltage appearing across your IGBT/resistor. R=U/I . Let's say the leakage current is 1uA, your acceptable max. voltage while off is 1V:  R=1V/1uA=1MΩ.